# Bash Regexp replace absolute paths with relative paths

Tags: regex, bash

I use the following code to iterate through some xml files.

```
for i in ./*.xml; do
    some line replacing content in the file $i
done
```

In every file I want to replace all strings describing absolute paths with their relative path starting at some dir.

---

Inside one of the xml files:

Before: `/home/user/workspace/proj/bin`

After: `./proj/bin`

### How can I do this with one line(regexp) bash inside my for loop? It would be nice if you can describe the regexp.

---

Can I do something like this?: sed -i 's/.*(/proj)/.$1/g' $i

1. Replace line by line globally.
2. Try to match the beginning of the path.
3. Save the part I want to keep and pre append a .

This does not work but it's an idea

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please include your current attempt, it'll be easier to get an idea of what needs explaining.

Comment: I think I want someting like sed -i 's/(.*)\/proj//g' $i

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do something like this:
>
> ```
> sed -i 's/.*(/proj)/.$1/g' $i
> ```

Yes, you can. You just need to

- either escape the `/`, or
- use a different delimiter.
- escape the match parenthesis

I prefer the latter approach:

```
for i in ./*.xml; do
    sed -i 's:\S*\(/proj\):.$1:g' "$i"
done
```

---

Reason for `"$i"` is explained [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362892/bash-regexp-replace-absolute-paths-with-relative-paths/23363478#comment35783944_23363478).

Reason for using `\S*` in the pattern: Suppose you have some string like:

> I will go to `/home/user/workspace/proj/bin` and delete stuff now.

Without using `\S*`, you'll end up with:

> `./proj/bin` and delete stuff now.

instead of:

> I will go to `./proj/bin` and delete stuff now.

Comment: You should also take care to double-quote the `"$i"`.  In general, any variable which contains a file name (and most others) must be double-quoted.

Comment: I tried this but I can not get it to work. I run: sed -i 's:\\S*(/proj):.$1:g' ./error_archiver.xml but the error_archiver.xml file is unchanged. Maybe im not using sed correctly. I tried sed -i 's:\\S*(/proj):.$1:g' ./error_archiver.xml >> newfile as well

Comment: The files are unchanged, it does not work:S Trying to figure out why

Comment: $1 is never evaluated

Answer (score 0):

is it necessary to use regexp? Why not simply:

`find . -type f -name "*.xml"`

in this way you will get directly the relative path (of course according to your CWD).

Comment: I don't want to find the files. I want to replace content in the files